# php code correction for time interval add

Tags: php

This is my current code and below is the output of this code.But I need to do some correction on this.

```
$startTimeInterval = 15;
$duration = 20;
$open = '2017-09-29T10:00:00-05:00';
$close = '2017-09-29T17:30:00-05:00';

$startTimeInterval = $startTimeInterval.' minutes';
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($startTimeInterval);
$begin = new DateTime($open);
$end = new DateTime($close);
$end->add($interval);

$periods = iterator_to_array(new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end));

$start = array_shift($periods);
$slot = array();
foreach ($periods as $time) {
    $slot[]= $start->format('h:iA'). ' - '. $time->format('h:iA');
    $start = $time;
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($slot);exit;
```

**OutPut**

```
[0] => 10:00AM - 10:15AM
[1] => 10:15AM - 10:30AM
[2] => 10:30AM - 10:45AM
[3] => 10:45AM - 11:00AM
[4] => 11:00AM - 11:15AM
........
[28] => 05:00PM - 05:15PM
[29] => 05:15PM - 05:30PM
```

**I need this**

```
[0] => 10:00AM - 10:20AM
[1] => 10:15AM - 10:35AM
[2] => 10:30AM - 10:50AM
[3] => 10:45AM - 11:05AM
[4] => 11:00AM - 11:20AM
........
[28] => 05:00PM - 05:20PM
[29] => 05:15PM - 05:35PM
```

Horizontally it will add duration and vertically it will add startTimeInterval

Comment: So change `$startTimeInterval` from `15` to `20`, no?

Comment: @chris85 check this link  https://go.booker.com/#/location/naturallywhitehouston/service/2239050/Boost%20Remineralizing%20Treatment%20/availability/2017-09-29/any-provider
I am making this type of work.

Comment: Okay, what's the question there? The different between what you have and want is 5 minutes, no?

Comment: start time will increment by $startTimeInterval, And the duration of particular time will increment with $duration.

Comment: @chris85 check this link https://go.booker.com/#/location/naturallywhitehouston/service/2233705/60%20minute%20cosmetic%20whitening/availability/2017-09-29/any-provider

$startTimeInterval and $duration is dynamic values. so we need to implement logic.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. PHP variables aren't exposed client side so a link isn't going to help me.

Comment: open   - open+duration   
1:00PM - 1:20PM    
open+startTimeInterval    open+startTimeInterval+duration
1:15PM - 1:30PM

Comment: You are not even using the `$duration` in your code its just a define. You need to calculated date one for periods one for +duration

Comment: Have you tried what I first said?

Comment: I just give a demo to you. I want to make like above link.
This is my input.
$startTimeInterval = 15;
$duration = 20;
$open = '2017-09-29T10:00:00-05:00';
$close = '2017-09-29T17:30:00-05:00';
And I want to make same as this link https://go.booker.com/#/location/naturallywhitehouston/service/2239050/Boost%20Remineralizing%20Treatment%20/availability/2017-09-29/any-provider
Did you know logic to make this result.

Comment: @Santa'shelper Till now I not use $duration. This is for your understanding. That I need to add on start time 10:00AM+$duration for each row.
And next row will make with 10:00AM+$startTimeInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is a solution:

Your `$time` is of type [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

You could [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the `$time` and in the loop add 5 minutes.

For example:

```
foreach ($periods as $time) {
    $clonedTime = clone $time;
    $clonedTime->modify('+5 minutes');

    $slot[]= $start->format('h:iA'). ' - '. $clonedTime->format('h:iA');
    $start = $time;
}
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:00AM - 10:20AM
    [1] => 10:15AM - 10:35AM
    [2] => 10:30AM - 10:50AM
    [3] => 10:45AM - 11:05AM
    [4] => 11:00AM - 11:20AM
    [5] => 11:15AM - 11:35AM
    [6] => 11:30AM - 11:50AM
    [7] => 11:45AM - 12:05PM
    [8] => 12:00PM - 12:20PM
    [9] => 12:15PM - 12:35PM
    [10] => 12:30PM - 12:50PM
    [11] => 12:45PM - 01:05PM
    [12] => 01:00PM - 01:20PM
    [13] => 01:15PM - 01:35PM
    [14] => 01:30PM - 01:50PM
    [15] => 01:45PM - 02:05PM
    [16] => 02:00PM - 02:20PM
    [17] => 02:15PM - 02:35PM
    [18] => 02:30PM - 02:50PM
    [19] => 02:45PM - 03:05PM
    [20] => 03:00PM - 03:20PM
    [21] => 03:15PM - 03:35PM
    [22] => 03:30PM - 03:50PM
    [23] => 03:45PM - 04:05PM
    [24] => 04:00PM - 04:20PM
    [25] => 04:15PM - 04:35PM
    [26] => 04:30PM - 04:50PM
    [27] => 04:45PM - 05:05PM
    [28] => 05:00PM - 05:20PM
    [29] => 05:15PM - 05:35PM
)
```